# Android Emulator SDK cannot access internet - web page not available. DNS not resolving; IP Address of URL works

Tags: android, android-emulator, dns, ip

I've been having issues with Android Emulator SDK  It's actually occurring on all versions and resolutions.  The error I'm having is URLs cannot be resolved by the DNS.  If I type in the IP Address for, say, Google, it works.  It's definitely a DNS issue.  I am using the Android Virtual Device Manager; I am NOT using Eclipse, Netbeans, or some other IDE for testing.  Is there a way to resolve this through the AVDM GUI, perhaps utilizing the Hardware Property/Value pairs?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Emulator is not connecting to internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252924/android-emulator-is-not-connecting-to-internet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a better answer.  The problem was resolved when I changed the nic adpater binding order.  I don't know why this was an issue, since I did not touch the binding order at any time, since working with the Android Emulator SDK.

I'm running a windows dev box; so, for those users, goto Control Panel -> Network Connections -> Advanced -> Advanced Settings -> Adapters and Binders -> Connections.

(source: http://forums.techarena.in/networking-security/1396635.htm).

Answer (score 2):

same issue is happening with me so i tried below command inside to

### ~/Android/Sdk/tools

```
emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_25 -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any option in the GUI to set the DNS.  This must be a bug with the emulator itself.  The only way I could fix it is run the emulator from the command-line-interface, i.e.

```
android @avd_name -dns-server x.x.x.x,x.x.x.x
```

You can set up to 4 dns server entries and there shouldn't be any spaces between dns entries.