# Visual Studio Xamarin and Android emulator without internet connection

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm developing a Xamarin project using Visual Studio 2015.

The issue is that I'm not able to start the Android Emulator from Visual Studio using Internet. I'm behind a proxy.

Using `HttpWebRequest`, I get the error:

> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Network is
>   unreachable)

I check out the emulator and no Internet connection detected:

[image]

I was able to start the emulator setting the proxy/dns using command line (using `emulator.exe -avd avdName -dns-server 192.168.1.1`), but not from Visual Studio.

My question is: is there any way to set proxy/dns configuration to Android Emulator from Visual Studio or in any configuration file, like .ini, or config.ini in Avd folder, or any other way?

Answer (score 13):

I'm pretty sure you resolved your problem since then, but I faced the same one and found the following solution :

In Preferences / Projects / Android, just set `-dns-server 8.8.8.8` in "additional emulator launch arguments" (not sure of how it translate in english though).

[Xamarin Visual Studio Community preferences (screen capture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S48T.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I didn't found *Android* in *Projects* preferences. I'm using VS 2015 Professional, maybe should I install some adicional extension?

Comment: For Windows go to Tools > Settings > Xamarin > Android Settings and you'll see "Additional Emulator Launch Arguments", you can put the emulator launch argument there.

Comment: In VS 2019 it's Tools > *Options* > Xamarin > Android Settings

Comment: Working in VS 2022 on Mac, where it's under Preferences -> Build and Debug -> Android. I'm surprised how many other possible answers to the problem I found before I saw this one!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new virtual external adapter in the Hyper-V administrator. Click on "virtual switch manager" and add an external one with your current connection. Then, once you have done that you have to go to your virtual machine settings and add the external adapter you have created before.

I put two screenshots for you to see my configuration.

[image: Virtual Switch Manager details]

[image: VM Settings]