# Android emulator networking on a proxy

Tags: android, networking, proxy, emulation

i Wish to test my app which needs network access on avd and on api 25. i am currently on a proxy network .i have looked at some of the answers from stackoverflow and have also looked at developer.google docs for doing this. I have tried starting the emulator from the command line by passing the necessary parameters using -http-proxy but it doesn't seem to work.The emulator starts but there is still no network access. Also i have changed the apn settings according to my proxy but that just limits my connection to the browser. and hence is not useful for my app. What should i do?? i use android studio 2.3.2 on windows 10.

Comment: Quick question did this work in a non-proxy environment?

Comment: yes it does work .

Comment: Have you set the dns parameter?

Comment: what do you mean by that?? dint get you

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252924/android-emulator-is-not-connecting-to-internet/43066809#43066809

Comment: if you are talking about the netstat one, yes i have done that and if you are talking about the dns one...i am not able to understand what he is trying to say...it would be good.if you guide me through

Comment: I want to exclude that you had a dns issue. You can solve the dns issue by adding "-dns-server 8.8.8.8" in command line, when you start the emulator, or by changing the network interface order. Since you have did one of the above it's not a dns issue.

Comment: I use charles proxy and it is working fine (either emulator on host or in docker container)