# Android studio 3.1.1 emulator with Google API can't connect to internet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

After update into android studio 3.1.1, then all my emulators (with Google API) can't connect to the internet. Google chrome, youtube app in those emulators can't access internet too. 
Tried many ways like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7252958/719212) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252924/android-emulator-is-not-connecting-to-internet). 
 
I also tried to reinstall android studio as well as sdk, but it didn't work.
Emulators without Google API can work well, but my project needs Google service to run 
Does anyone know how to fix this issue?